# CSS3 No Bullets With Float: Left

Tags: css, css-float

I've made a change somewhere on my website that I can not back track, and for some reason I have my lost CSS3 bullets globally in all my **horizontal lists**. But regardless, it seems to me that that this code should work...but with the float: left I loose the bullets and can not keep them. Can anyone tell me please why I am not able to retain the bullets with the float: left?

```
ul#info {
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

ul#info li:first-child {
    list-style: none;
}

ul#info li {
    list-style: disc;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 20%;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Floating an element changes it to a *block box*, which ignores the display type unless it is set to *none*.  Since the elements are not of `display: list-item` anymore, none of the list related properties will effect it either.

You could inject your own disc on the before pseudo element like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/eyDc6/

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}

li:before {
    content: "\2022";
}
```

Comment: So how do I work around this to have a horizontal list with bullets? I seen numerous examples and I used to make it work. I don't know why I can't make it work now.

Comment: I've updated my answer showing how you can do it on the before element.

Answer (score 1):

Your bullets are hiding off the left edge of your ul - their width isn't considered when the browser decides where to float the list to. Try adding some left padding and/or margin.

Edit: Or not, although I have seen this happen. You could always use a css :before selector (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) as a workaround.

Comment: No... the bullets simply aren't drawn at all.

Comment: BoltClock is correct, the bullets are not showinng at all. I added margin: 10px; and no success.

Comment: The :before psuedo element was a good idea, but I still couldn't make it work: li:before { list-style: disc }

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a list floating on the right of an image.
The bullet goes on the image and were no longer align with the rest of the floating text.

This piece of css solve my problem.

`ul { overflow: hidden; }`

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `display: inline-block` instead of `float:left` in this case

Comment: This'll work if you're using the float to shrink-wrap the list, but if you actually wants to float it it's not going to help.

Comment: I can't use display: inline-block and keep bullets, so this is why I went with the float: left instead. But regardless out of desperation I tried both to no success.